# SingleOrDefault and FirstOrDefault returning cached data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Some previous code I had written used the `Find()` method to retrieve single entities by their primary key:

```
return myContext.Products.Find(id)
```

This worked great because I had this code tucked into a generic class, and each entity had a different field name as its primary key.

But I had to replace the code because I noticed that it was returning cached data, and I need it to return data from the database each call.  Microsoft's documentation confirmed this is the behavior of `Find()`.

So I changed my code to use `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`.  I haven't found anything in documentation that states these methods return cached data.

Now I am executing these steps:

1. Save an entity via EF.
2. Execute an UPDATE statement in SSMS to update the recently saved
   record's Description field.
3. Retrieve the entity into a new entity variable using `SingleOrDefault`
   or `FirstOrDefault`.

The entities being returned still have the old value in the `Description` field.

I have run a SQL trace, and verified that the data is being queried during step 3.  This baffles me - if EF is making a round trip to the database, why is it returning cached data?

I've searched online, and most answers apply to the `Find()` method.  Furthermore, they suggest some solutions that are merely workarounds (dispose the `DbContext` and instantiate a new one) or solutions that won't work for me (use the `AsNoTracking()` method).

How can I retrieve my entities from the database and bypass the EF cache?

Comment: unit of work implies that you'll receive entity from context if you do have it in context; so EF found entity in DB and uses that ID to return entity from context. you have many options, like detach "cached" entity from context before query, or load entity to new context and then attach it etc, but all these workarounds shout "you using me wrong"

Comment: Without more information, I agree with @Lanorkin. The reason this is rarely an issue is because a `DbContext` object should be scoped and have a very short lifespan (like for only the life of one HTTP request). In such a short time, there isn't a reason to go back to the database to get the same record twice. I suspect your `DbContext` object has been alive too long.

Comment: do you find the right solution @ChadSC???

Answer (score 8):

The behaviour you're seeing is described in Microsoft's [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/overview#the-life-of-a-query) article under point 3:

> 3. For each item in the result set
>
> > a. If this is a tracking query, EF checks if the data represents an entity already in the change tracker for the context instance
> >
> > - If so, the existing entity is returned

It's described a little better in [this blog post](http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/):

> It turns out that Entity Framework uses the [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) pattern. This means that once an entity with a given key is loaded in the context’s cache, it is never loaded again for as long as that context exists. So when we hit the database a second time to get the customers, it retrieved the updated `851` record from the database, but because customer `851` was already loaded in the context, it ignored the newer record from the database ([more](http://rlacovara.blogspot.com/2009/03/entity-framework-patterns-identity-map.html) [details](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/12/08/identity-maps.aspx)).

All of this is saying that if you make a query, it checks the primary key first to see if it already has it in the cache. If so, it uses what's in the cache.

How do you avoid it? The first is to make sure you're not keeping your `DbContext` object alive too long. `DbContext` objects are only designed to be used for one unit of work. Bad things happen if you keep it around too long, like excessive memory consumption.

- Do you need to retrieve data to display to the user? Create a `DbContext` to get the data and discard that `DbContext`.
- Do you need to update a record? Create a new `DbContext`, update the record and discard that `DbContext`.

This is why, when you use EF Core [with dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection) in ASP.NET Core, it is created with a [scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes) lifetime, so any `DbContext` object only lives for the life of one HTTP request.

In the rare case you really do need to get fresh data for a record you already have an object for, you can use [EntityEntry.Reload()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.reload)/[EntityEntry.ReloadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.reloadasync) like this:

```
myContext.Entry(myProduct).Reload();
```

That doesn't help you if you only know the ID though.

If you really *really* need to reload an entity that you only have the ID for, you could do something weird like this:

```
private Product GetProductById(int id) {
    //check if it's in the cache already
    var cachedEntity = myContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Product>()
                           .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Entity.Id == id);
    if (cachedEntity == null) {
        //not in cache - get it from the database
        return myContext.Products.Find(id);
    } else {
        //we already have it - reload it
        cachedEntity.Reload();
        return cachedEntity.Entity;
    }
}
```

But again, this should only be used in limited cases, when you've already addressed any cases of long-living `DbContext` object because unwanted caching isn't the only consequence.

Comment: Finally how to retrieve the latest changes and bypass the EF cache? I have the same problem and confused :(

Comment: @PeymanMajidi This answer describes how to do that. But your problem is most likely that you're reusing your `DbContext` object when you should not be.

Comment: What a fantastic answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have the same problem and finally found the answer,
You doing everything right, that's just how EF works.
You can use `.AsNoTracking()` for your purposes:

```
return myContext.Products.AsNoTracking().Find(id)
```

make sure you added`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` at the top.

It works like a magic

Comment: more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-5.0.0#System_Data_Entity_DbExtensions_AsNoTracking_System_Linq_IQueryable_

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do this and make changes to that object, your changes won't be saved when you call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: reallllly? Why dotnet core made everything wired :(

Comment: That's not specific to .NET Core. It was true in the old Entity Framework too, which is the documentation you linked to. [This is the documentation for `AsNoTracking()` in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asnotracking?view=efcore-5.0). If you want to understand when you'd use `AsNoTracking()`, you can read this article: [Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, You know When I run `firstOrDefault` I expected to get the latest values, and It is so obvious~!!. still running SQL queries is the best :)

Comment: You should almost never retrieve the same record a second time with the same `DbContext`. You're probably reusing your `DbContext` when you should not be.